# reset an element after ajax post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am using the Bluimp Jquery File Upload plugin to upload files to S3. Everything works fine, except that, once I have uploaded 1 file, I cannot upload another. The element is still present on the page, but it seems like the event listener has stopped working perhaps. Essentially, I would just like to reload one div (.activity-post).

I have tried the following:

```
      $(".activity-post").load();
      $(".activity-post").load(window.location.href  + ".activity-post");
      document.getElementById('#inputfile').reset(); //also doesnt work.
```

This is the loadActivity() function:

```
function loadActivity() {
  var competitionId = $("body").attr("data-competitionId");
  var url = "activity_api.php?competitionId=" + competitionId;

   $.get(url, function(data) {
     $("#activityspot").html(data);
   });
 }
```

Here is the script:

```
 $('#inputfile').fileupload({
    url: 'upload.php?competitionId=<?php echo $_GET['competitionId']; ?>',
    sequentialUploads : true,
    dataType: 'text',
    progressall: function (e, data) {
            $(".loader").show();
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
       loadActivity();
       console.log("updating activity feed");
       //reset element here. 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please post the content of `loadActivity()`

Comment: `document.getElementById('#inputfile').reset()` won't work, of course... try `document.forms[0].reset()` or `document.getElementById('inputfile').reset()` or `$('#inputfile').reset()` or `document.querySelector('#inputfile').reset()` or...

Comment: Perhaps I need to reset that element BEFORE I run loadActivity() ?